# Implement specfic behaviour based on type in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am building a React site in which I want to display articles (I call them "Previews").

Articles can be either text or images/videos. I declared two interfaces (*TextPreviewProps* and *ImgVidPreviewProps*) that share some common properties (`id`, `type`) but also differ on others (*TextPreviewProps* has a `text` property while *ImgVidPreviewProps* has a `file` property for instance).

```js
export interface TextPreviewProps {
    id: number;
    type: "text";
    text: string;
    onChangeText?: (newText: string) => void;
}

export interface ImgVidPreviewProps {
    id: number;
    type: "image" | "video";
    file: File;
}

export type ContentPreviewProps = TextPreviewProps | ImgVidPreviewProps;
```

I have declared a type alias *ContentPreviewProps* that can be either a *TextPreviewProps* or a *ImgVidPreviewProps*.

My function that renders a "Preview" takes a *ContentPreviewProps* as input, and I want it to return a different React Component based on whether the input was Text or Image/Video. Since we cannot truly dynamically typecheck in Typescript, what is the best way to do this ?

At the moment, I check whether the `type` property is "text" or "image"/"video", and I then cast the *ContentPreviewProps* object to either a *TextPreviewProps* or a *ImgVidPreviewProps* based on the value of `type`.

```js
const renderPreview = (
        content: ContentPreviewProps
    ): JSX.Element => {
        const { type, id } = content;

        if (type === "text") {
            const textContent = content as TextPreviewProps;
            return (
                <TextPreview
                    type={type}
                    text={textContent.text}
                    onChangeText={(newText: string) => console.log(newText)}
                    id={id}
                />
            );
        }

        const imgVidContent = content as ImgVidPreviewProps;
        return (
            <ImgVidPreview
                type={type}
                file={imgVidContent.file}
                id={id}
            />
        );
    };
```

However, there is redundancy in this approach, as I have to both check the `type` and then cast the object based on the result of that check.

**What is the idiomatic way to implement such type-specific behaviour at runtime in Typescript ?**

Comment: This is a perfect example of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions), which TypeScript already supports. The problem here is that you have pulled `content.type` into its own variable before you check it, which TypeScript won't follow. If you check the property directly: `if (content.type === "text") { ... }` then the cast should no longer be necessary.

Comment: Thank you, this works great ! Maybe you could turn this comment into an answer so I can validate it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do that:

```
export type ContentPreviewProps = TextPreviewProps | ImgVidPreviewProps;
```

Then, as from the prop `type` in both `TextPreviewProps` and `ImgVidPreviewProps` will determine which of these will be pointed at in type `ContentPreviewProps`.

So, when you recieve prop `type: string = "text"` the `ContentPreviewProps` would idiomatically be:

```
{
    id: number;
    type: "text";
    text: string;
    onChangeText?: (newText: string) => void;
}
```

Thus, when used, you don't have to cast depending on `type` prop value! since you already did that when you declared that type:

```
export type ContentPreviewProps = TextPreviewProps | ImgVidPreviewProps;
```

You may modify you code as:

*AS from Ewaren update below, destructring the `type` out of `content` was the cause of the problem.*

```
const renderPreview = (
        content: ContentPreviewProps
    ): JSX.Element => {
        if (content.type === "text") { // TS won't complain about textContent.text since you are validating it here.
            return (
                <TextPreview
                    type={content.type}
                    text={content.text}
                    onChangeText={(newText: string) => console.log(newText)}
                    id={content.id}
                />
            );
        }

        return (
            <ImgVidPreview
                type={content.type}
                file={content.file}
                id={content.id}
            />
        );
    };
```

I believe TS won't complain about any of this. since you are conditionally checking `type`.

Comment: Well this is what I expected from TS, but when I try to write it as you explained, I get the following error message : `Property 'text' does not exist on type 'ContentPreviewProps'.
  Property 'text' does not exist on type 'ImgVidPreviewProps'.  TS2339`. So it seems that TS actually doesn't understand that it needs to cast.

Comment: Update: CRice's comment explains why your solution didn't work as is, I should not have destructured `content` before checking its type.

Comment: Yes it did, you can update your answer removing the destructuring and I will validate it

Comment: It's basically your solution @Ewaren, I will update my answer, but U can also post ur own answer and accept it ;)